# Error reading s3 bucket it spark

Tags: scala, hadoop, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, apache-spark

Im getting an exception when trying to read files from s3 with spark. Error and code is given below. The folder consists of a number of files called part-00000 part-00001 etc output from hadoop. They have a range of file sizes from 0kb to several gb

> 16/04/07 15:38:58 INFO NativeS3FileSystem: Opening key
>   'titlematching214/1.0/bypublicdemand/part-00000' for reading at
>   position '0' 16/04/07 15:38:58 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 0.0
>   in stage 0.0 (TID 0) org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3.S3Exception:
>   org.jets3t.service.S3ServiceException: S3 GET failed for
>   '/titlematching214%2F1.0%2Fbypublicdemand%2Fpart-00000' XML Error
>   Message: `InvalidRange`The
>   requested range is not
>   satisfiablebytes=0-01AED523DF401F17ECBYUH1h3WkC7/g8/EFE/YyHbzxoNTpRBiX6QMy2RXHur17lYTZXd7XxOWivmqIpu0F7Xx5zdWns=

```
object ReadMatches extends App{
  override def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val config = new SparkConf().setAppName("RunAll").setMaster("local")
    val sc = new SparkContext(config)
    val hadoopConf = sc.hadoopConfiguration
    hadoopConf.set("fs.hdfs.impl", "org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem")
    hadoopConf.set("fs.file.impl", "org.apache.hadoop.fs.LocalFileSystem")
    sc.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.s3n.awsAccessKeyId", "myRealKeyId")
    sc.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.s3n.awsSecretAccessKey", "realKey")
    val sqlConext = new SQLContext(sc)

    val datset = sc.textFile("s3n://altvissparkoutput/titlematching214/1.0/*/*")
    val ebayRaw = sqlConext.read.json(datset)
    val data = ebayRaw.first();
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you, please, try with this `sc.hadoopConfiguration.set("mapreduce.input.fileinputformat.input.dir.recursive","true")`. Also I believe s3n protocol limits file sizes to 5GB. Completely unsure if that might be the issue, but...

Comment: No difference, same error.

Comment: were you able to fix this error?

Comment: Nope, if i had fixed it i would have put the solution here. I ended up just working around the problem

Answer (score 0):

May be you can read your dataset straight from `s3`.

```
    val datset = "s3n://altvissparkoutput/titlematching214/1.0/*/*"
    val ebayRaw = sqlConext.read.json(datset)
```